# I need a way around using they soft keyboard for mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Scenario:
I have an web app where I need to capture all keyed input to the page in a central location.  My first solution was to continually give focus to a text box so all focus would go through there.  That works amazingly for desktop browsers, but causes the undesirable effect of causing the soft keyboard on mobile browsers to always be visible.  Since my keyed input is coming from an external source, I don't want the keyboard visible until I request it.  Since there's no direct way (that I've found) to do this, I was trying to give constant focus to a control that doesn't cause the keyboard to show.  I was unable to find a control that didn't cause the keyboard to show, but would fire one of the key events (keydown/keyup/keypress).

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can catch all keyed input without displaying the soft keyboard?

Note:  I can have a different solution for desktop and mobile if necessary.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When you say coming from an 'external source', what do you mean? Have you tried capturing a window.keydown event instead, which doesn't need a focused input?

Comment: My suggestion would be to have a keyboard icon which, when clicked, would bring focus to the (presumably hidden) textbox instead of it being always focused (at least when a mobile browser is detected)

Comment: @JesseKernaghan  The external input is any physical device attached or paired to the mobile device that would send input.  Typically it would use a keyboard wedge (virtual keyboard driver).

Comment: @JonathanGray  I can handle showing the keyboard whenever I want it, that's easy.  I need a way to receive input without the keyboard showing, and I can't do that when a textbox has focus.  I need something to receive the input that won't prompt the keyboard to display.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer was so simple, I can't believe it took me so long to get to it.

If you make a textbox readonly, it doesn't show the keyboard, but still fires key events.  This allowed me to accept input from the external source without showing the keyboard.  I also added a keyboard toggle button that simply hid the readonly textbox and showed the regular one.

If my application would have been different, I could have just added and removed the readonly attribute and applied focus again to have the same effect.

Thanks for all replies, including the ones that got deleted.

Comment: I didn't understand that you wanted keyed input from a source other than the actual keyboard presented to the user -- had you been more specific I'm sure you would have received better input

Comment: This sounds like a hacky way of doing things anyways. Since this data is going to be processed client-side, I really hope you're not planning on trusting this data at all (verify it)

Comment: "Since my keyed input is coming from an external source, I don't want the keyboard visible until I request it."  ...that would indicate a source other than the device.  Specificity wasn't the problem, interpretation was.

While I don't prefer to "hack" it this way, no better/viable solution has presented itself. Given the alternative methods I tried to get this problem resolved, this solution is down right elegant!

As for the validity of the data, that's not a concern. Only a moron takes client side input without server side validation. All service layer input is validated server side. Cheers

Comment: I read and re-read what you stated, now for a third time, but stand by my statement. You weren't clear enough (for at least myself to understand right away). The other suggestions would have worked for your situation, however I'm afraid you just didn't understand how to actually implement it. I would have explained the implementation myself had I understood correctly what you were trying to do in the first place.

Comment: Interpretation issues are preventable, and you're the one looking for information.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for information.  None came, so I was nice enough to provide the solution when I found it.  You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
var keyedinput = "";
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){keyedinput += String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)}, false);
```

`keyedinput` will contain the contents of the keyed input from the external keyboard-like device. Simply reference it as a global variable when needed. If there is an enter/esc key or and "end" key (sequence?) you can just check the corresponding `keyCode` to launch an action with the contents of the variable instead of appending to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, while your solution might work great for a desktop browser, it is hit and miss for mobile browsers (more miss than hit) as it most often doesn't fire in web-kit mobile browsers, among others.  It's too bad that the previous person who suggested something very similar to your suggestion decided to delete their comment and all accompanying conversation because it might have saved you a little time.  Thanks for your suggestion though!